# Unable to install package in R Studio- Unable to translate...to native encoding

Tags: r, package

I am unable to install the package from my R Studio. Not sure what's the meaning of "unable to translate...to native encoding"..
Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to translate 'C:/Users/molly/OneDrive/<U+6587><U+6863>/R/win-library/4.0' to native encoding
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/mvtnorm_1.1-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 268839 bytes (262 KB)
downloaded 262 KB

package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\molly\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyMACBs\downloaded_packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to translate 'C:/Users/molly/OneDrive/<U+6587><U+6863>/R/win-library/4.0' to native encoding
Warning messages:
1: In base::list.dirs(.libPaths(), full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE) :
  unable to translate 'C:/Users/molly/OneDrive/<U+6587><U+6863>/R/win-library/4.0' to native encoding
2: In list.files(.rs.uniqueLibraryPaths(), full.names = TRUE) :
  unable to translate 'C:/Users/molly/OneDrive/<U+6587><U+6863>/R/win-library/4.0' to native encoding
3: In list.files(.rs.uniqueLibraryPaths(), full.names = TRUE) :
  unable to translate 'C:/Users/molly/OneDrive/<U+6587><U+6863>/R/win-library/4.0' to native encoding
```

Comment: The package was installed. You got a warning, not an error.

Comment: lol my bad.. Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 1):

If it can't encode,

You need to:

1. Create the folder for future packages
2. Navigate to C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.4\etc
3. Create there an empty file "`.site`"
4. Rename the empty file " " to "`Renviron`"( so you'll get `Renviron.site` )
5. Write in file: `"R_LIBS_USER=c:/Name_of_ur_folder"`

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Following the order: Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Saving:

In the "Default text encoding" section, set the encoding to "UTF-8" or other suitable one.